# Is ARP applicable out of a subnet?

Tags: networking, arp

When a computer, with IP address IPs and default gateway IPg, is sending a datagram to destination with IP address IPd on a different subnet, it will perform: 
a)- ARP(IPg) 
b)- ARP( IPd) 
c)- ARP(IPs) 
d)- ARP(0)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Sending packet to another subnet actually means sending packet to gateway, since gateway is responsible for proper routing between subnets. Thus computer will perform discovery of gateway MAC address unless it's cached.